# Wtforms, Multi selection file upload

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a form contains name and pictures

MyForm:

```
    name = TextField(
    u'name',
    validators=[
        validators.DataRequired(),
        validators.Length(min=1, max=25)
    ]
)   

    pictures = FileField(
    u'pictures',
    validators=[
        FileRequired(),
        FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png'], 'Images only!')
    ]
)
```

Jinja2 template:

```
{% from "_form_helpers.tpl" import render_field %}
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <dl>
    {{ render_field(form.name) }}
    {{ render_field(form.pictures) }}
  </dl>
  <p>{{ form.submit }}
</form>
```

I want to upload one or more picture in a single field (Multi selection).

How to do this?

Thanks..

Answer (score 9):

You need to specify the multiple attribute for the input tag. This can be done in your templates like so:

`form.pictures(multiple="")`

which will result in your generated html allowing for multiple file selection:

`<input id="pictures" multiple name="pictures" type="file">`

#### How to Manipulate multiple files using request.files:

```
    images = request.files.getlist("pictures")
    if images:
        for img in images:
            # Create Images
            file_name = str(uuid.uuid4()) + secure_filename(img.filename)
            image_file = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], file_name)
            img.save(image_file)

            # Save record
            image = models.Image(record_id=record.record_id,
                                 file_name=file_name.encode('utf-8'))
            db.session.add(image)

    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: That lets you select multiple, but with something like request.files, you only get one key this way through WTF. Can you elaborate on how you are manipulating this on the back end?

Comment: I have added a code snippet from an old project that may answer your question.

Answer (score 5):

From: http://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html

> **render_kw** (dict) – If provided, a dictionary which provides default
>   keywords that will be given to the widget at render time.

Therefore, you can pass `{multiple: True}` to the field definition as below:

**forms.py**

```
class UploadImages(Form):

    imgs = FileField(
        'Select images',
        render_kw={'multiple': True},
    )
    upload = SubmitField('Upload')
```

**uploade_template.html**

```
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since version 2.2 wtforms supports `MultipleFileField`. (From https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changes.html#version-2-2)